# I am trying to use a List within dart to Store information

Tags: flutter, list, dart

**How can I retrieve this information as when I am testing it using print it is returning the following error?**

I have searched online to try and find a solution but alas for the past 30 minutes i have not been able to find one. If there is an easier and more efficient way of storing information then please let me know.

Apologies as I am still learning dart, moving from JS.

```
List<Object> chosenSelection = [
    [
      'Advanced Higher', //[0][0]
      false /**Enabled? */, //[0][1]
      [
        'Style',
        'MelodyHarmony',
        'RhythmTempo',
        'TextureStructureForm',
        'Timbre',
      ] /**Categories */, //[0][2][0-4]
    ],//[0]
    [
      'Higher', //[0][0]
      false /**Enabled? */, //[0][1]
      [
        'Style',
        'MelodyHarmony',
        'RhythmTempo',
        'TextureStructureForm',
        'Timbre',
      ] /**Categories */, //[0][2][0-4]
    ]
  ];
  
  
  print(chosenSelection[0][0]); //Output: 'Advanced Higher'
  print (chosenSelection[0][2][4]); // Output 'Timbre'
```

Resulting error:
*type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List' of 'function result'*

**I am trying to access the data 'Advanced Higher' and then 'Timbre' within the variable.**

Comment: what's error are you getting

Comment: im having trouble accessing the variable and outputting the wanted results at the bottom via the print command.

Comment: i mean are you getting any error when you are printing these using the print statement?

Comment: ive attached the error to the post now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up settling for making the information part of a class.

```html
class ChosenLevel {
  String level;
  bool overallToggled = false;
  Map categories = {
    'Style': true,
    'MelodyHarmony': false,
    'RhythmTempo': false,
    'TextureStructureForm': false,
    'Timbre': false,
  };
  Color _color;

  ChosenLevel(this.level, this._color);

  get categoriesNumber {
    return categories.length;
  }

  specificCategory(index) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        return 'Style';
      case 1:
        return 'MelodyHarmony';
      case 2:
        return 'RhythmTempo';
      case 3:
        return 'TextureStructureForm';
      case 4:
        return 'Timbre';
      /* default:
        throw ("Something strange happend"); */
    }
  }

  toggleCat(c) {
    this.categories['${c}'] = !this.categories['${c}'];
  }

  toggleLevel() {
    this.overallToggled = !this.overallToggled;
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{${level}, ${categories}}';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's the question here, but this code doesn't compile for 2 reasons:

1. You're missing a closed bracket in the second print;
2. You're trying to access the elements of an Object as if it is a nested List.

Comment: My question is how would i access the variable for the Outputs I have said I wanted?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to implement a 2d and 3d list. But you have declared a 1d list.

In order to declare a 2d list you need to declare it as `List<List<Object>>` and for a 3d list: `List<List<List<Object>>>`

So you need to declare `List<List<List<Object>>> chosenSelection`, and then

```
print(chosenSelection[0][0]); //Output: 'Advanced Higher'
  print (chosenSelection[0][2][4]); // Output 'Timbre'
```

Comment: This still returned an error.

Comment: What is your error message?